# Regex Unclosed character class in Java; escaping doesn't solve issue

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex in JS flavor

```
^[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

I tried it in JS and it worked for me (only want to match URL that does not start with the HTTP/HTTPS protocol):
https://regex101.com/r/6y2Gnd/2

Now I want to use the same regex in my Java backend. At first I got the error

> Unclosed character class

Upon reading into it, I realized I have to escape the `\` slash. I basically added three `\\\` to every `\` slash. The result is:

```
^[\\\\w.-]+(?:\\\\.[\\\\w\\\\.-]+)+[\\\\w\\\\-\\\\._~:/?#[\\\\]@!\\\\$&'\\\\(\\\\)\\\\*\\\\+,;=.]+$
```

Even though the compiler doesn't show any errors anymore, the result was empty, i.e. it couldn't match the cases like it did with in JS flavor.

I tested the Java regex [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) and in my code.

```
www.web.de # I want to match this
web.de # I want to match this
http://web.de # I do NOT want to match this
https://www.web.de # I do NOT want to match this
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Why are you turning a single '\' into '\\\\'? Have you tried just '\\'?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I've tried that too: `^[\\w.-]+(?:\\.[\\w\\.-]+)+[\\w\\-\\._~:/?#\[\\]@!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=.]+$`. Still no matches. I escaped because of Java. I've been told that java behaves like that.

Comment: You only have one slash in front of the [

Comment: Like so? `^[\\w.-]+(?:\\.[\\w\\.-]+)+[\\w\\-\\._~:/?#\[\\]@!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=.]+$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following regex works well in Java regex tester:

```
^[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#\[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

Please try it yourself. Backslash should be added in the front of the [ character.

Comment: I added `^[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#\[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$` into https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output But no matches found

Comment: I just tested and it works. Multiline checkbox should be selected.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It's working